# jQuery get meta content in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get some data stored in a div and in a meta tag.

Here the div:

```
<div id="qtip-0" class="qtip simcal-default-calendar simcal-event-bubble qtip-pos-tc qtip-fixed qtip-focus" tracking="false" role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="false" aria-describedby="qtip-0-content" aria-hidden="false" data-qtip-id="0" >
<div class="qtip-tip">
    <canvas width="16" height="16" style="background-color: transparent !important; border: 0px !important; width: 8px; height: 8px;"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="qtip-content" id="qtip-0-content" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="simcal-event-details simcal-tooltip-content" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 title-event-container">
            <span class="simcal-event-title" itemprop="name">Riunione intenra Scali ferroviari</span>
        </div>
        <p><label>Luogo:</label><br>
        <span class="simcal-event-address simcal-event-start-location" itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta itemprop="name" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia"><meta itemprop="address" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia">Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia</span></p>
        <div id="map">Mappa</div>
        <p> 
            <a href="//maps.google.com?q=Palazzo+Marino+-+Comune+di+MilanoPiazza+della+Scala+2%2C+20121+Milano%2C+Italia" target="_blank">Vedi mappa ingrandita</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to access to:

```
<meta itemprop="address" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia">
```

to get the `content` attribute.

Here what I have tried:

```
var currentEventAddress = $('#qtip-0 span').find('meta[itemprop="address"]').attr('content');

console.log(currentEventAddress);
```

But I get `undefined`

Comment: Have you tried use HTML data attributes instead? They are useful for this kind of thing and are automatically accessible through `$('.element').data()`.

Comment: with `$('#qtip-0 span').find('meta[itemprop="address"]').data();` I still get `undefined`

Comment: There is currently no data in `<meta itemprop="address" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia">` though. Change it to `<meta itemprop="address" data-content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia">` and you should be able to run `$('#qtip-0 span').find('meta[itemprop="address"]').data('content');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var currentEventAddress = $('#qtip-0').find('meta[itemprop="address"]').attr('content');

console.log(currentEventAddress);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qtip-0" class="qtip simcal-default-calendar simcal-event-bubble qtip-pos-tc qtip-fixed qtip-focus" tracking="false" role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="false" aria-describedby="qtip-0-content" aria-hidden="false" data-qtip-id="0">
  <div class="qtip-tip">
    <canvas width="16" height="16" style="background-color: transparent !important; border: 0px !important; width: 8px; height: 8px;"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="qtip-content" id="qtip-0-content" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="simcal-event-details simcal-tooltip-content" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
      <div class="col-xs-12 title-event-container">
        <span class="simcal-event-title" itemprop="name">Riunione intenra Scali ferroviari</span>
      </div>
      <p><label>Luogo:</label><br>
        <span class="simcal-event-address simcal-event-start-location" itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta itemprop="name" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia"><meta itemprop="address" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia">Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia</span></p>
      <div id="map">Mappa</div>
      <p>
        <a href="//maps.google.com?q=Palazzo+Marino+-+Comune+di+MilanoPiazza+della+Scala+2%2C+20121+Milano%2C+Italia" target="_blank">Vedi mappa ingrandita</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Use this `$('#qtip-0').find('meta[itemprop="address"]').attr('content')` if you want to add span use `$('#qtip-0 span.simcal-event-address')`

Because the span that contains the meta is the span with class `simcal-event-address`

```js
var currentEventAddress = $('#qtip-0 span.simcal-event-address').find('meta[itemprop="address"]').attr('content');

console.log(currentEventAddress);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qtip-0" class="qtip simcal-default-calendar simcal-event-bubble qtip-pos-tc qtip-fixed qtip-focus" tracking="false" role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="false" aria-describedby="qtip-0-content" aria-hidden="false" data-qtip-id="0">
  <div class="qtip-tip">
    <canvas width="16" height="16" style="background-color: transparent !important; border: 0px !important; width: 8px; height: 8px;"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="qtip-content" id="qtip-0-content" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="simcal-event-details simcal-tooltip-content" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
      <div class="col-xs-12 title-event-container">
        <span class="simcal-event-title" itemprop="name">Riunione intenra Scali ferroviari</span>
      </div>
      <p><label>Luogo:</label><br>
        <span class="simcal-event-address simcal-event-start-location" itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta itemprop="name" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia"><meta itemprop="address" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia">Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia</span></p>
      <div id="map">Mappa</div>
      <p>
        <a href="//maps.google.com?q=Palazzo+Marino+-+Comune+di+MilanoPiazza+della+Scala+2%2C+20121+Milano%2C+Italia" target="_blank">Vedi mappa ingrandita</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find `meta` tag and its `attr` content direct.

```js
var currentEventAddress = $('#qtip-0 span').find('meta').attr('content');
alert(currentEventAddress)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qtip-0" class="qtip simcal-default-calendar simcal-event-bubble qtip-pos-tc qtip-fixed qtip-focus" tracking="false" role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="false" aria-describedby="qtip-0-content" aria-hidden="false" data-qtip-id="0">
  <div class="qtip-tip">
    <canvas width="16" height="16" style="background-color: transparent !important; border: 0px !important; width: 8px; height: 8px;"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="qtip-content" id="qtip-0-content" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="simcal-event-details simcal-tooltip-content" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
      <div class="col-xs-12 title-event-container">
        <span class="simcal-event-title" itemprop="name">Riunione intenra Scali ferroviari</span>
      </div>
      <p>
        <label>Luogo:</label>
        <br>
        <span class="simcal-event-address simcal-event-start-location" itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta itemprop="name" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia"><meta itemprop="address" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia">Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia</span></p>
      <div id="map">Mappa</div>
      <p>
        <a href="//maps.google.com?q=Palazzo+Marino+-+Comune+di+MilanoPiazza+della+Scala+2%2C+20121+Milano%2C+Italia" target="_blank">Vedi mappa ingrandita</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need find.

Use like this:

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
 var currentEventAddress = $('meta[itemprop="address"]').attr('content');
  alert(currentEventAddress)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Get Meta</button>

<div id="qtip-0" class="qtip simcal-default-calendar simcal-event-bubble qtip-pos-tc qtip-fixed qtip-focus" tracking="false" role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="false" aria-describedby="qtip-0-content" aria-hidden="false" data-qtip-id="0" >
<div class="qtip-tip">
    <canvas width="16" height="16" style="background-color: transparent !important; border: 0px !important; width: 8px; height: 8px;"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="qtip-content" id="qtip-0-content" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="simcal-event-details simcal-tooltip-content" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 title-event-container">
            <span class="simcal-event-title" itemprop="name">Riunione intenra Scali ferroviari</span>
        </div>
        <p><label>Luogo:</label><br>
        <span class="simcal-event-address simcal-event-start-location" itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta itemprop="name" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia"><meta itemprop="address" content="Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia">Palazzo Marino - Comune di Milano
Piazza della Scala 2, 20121 Milano, Italia</span></p>
        <div id="map">Mappa</div>
        <p> 
            <a href="//maps.google.com?q=Palazzo+Marino+-+Comune+di+MilanoPiazza+della+Scala+2%2C+20121+Milano%2C+Italia" target="_blank">Vedi mappa ingrandita</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple thing make this work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($("meta[itemprop='address']").attr("content"));
  });
</script>
```